# Facebook Graph API custom action with link, link getting removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app that is posting custom actions, similar to how Instagram does. I was putting a link at the end of the message property when the user posted just like Instagram was, example: "Here is a message - http://domain.com/123". Now all of a sudden none of these links are showing up anymore, even on old posts, so now my message for my old post reads "Here is a message - "

Why is this? Did something change with security or something?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no related change reported in Facebook developers blog. But this is strange why don't you link your facebook aggregation by using the following meta-data ?

```
 <meta property="og:url"  content="" />
```

p.s. these are the most recent changes that have been on effect, and there is no related thing here

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/#november-2012

Comment: I'm already linking my URL with that tag. I've also noticed that Instagram posts don't have the URL anymore either.

Comment: so facebook doing something without telling about it in the developers blog. That's quite strange! thanks for the update

Comment: Logged a bug with Facebook here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/167417236738143?browse=search_50b54810660bc3f37557022